# React app deployed to GitHub Pages gives "Site not found"

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, create-react-app

I'm trying to deploy a create-react-app to GitHub Pages, but I'm getting a 404.

> 404
>
> There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

What I've done:

- Created a user site repo named `<username>.github.io`
- Added `"homepage": "https://<username>.github.io"` to `package.json` ([as per the Create React App docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom))
- Installed the [`gh-pages`](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages) package
- Added and ran `"deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"` to `scripts` in `package.json`

The contents of `/build` folder is successfully pushed to master, but the site isn't accessible.

The repo's GitHub Pages settings simply says:

> Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the master branch.
>
> *User pages must be built from the master branch.*

I also tried some routing solutions ([this](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages) and [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765#issuecomment-327615099)) without making any difference, although I don't think they are ment to fix the problem I'm having.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this any further. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, so apparently you have to choose a GitHub Pages *theme* (even though you're not using it) in order for the page to be published. This seems very strange to me, and from what I can tell it's not at all mentioned in the documentation. ‍♂️

Comment: For anyone wondering how to do that  https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-with-the-theme-chooser

Comment: This also helped me out: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages. Has other documentations on Netlify, Heroku, Vercel...